# PHP strtotime and JavaScript Date.parse return different timestamps

Tags: php, javascript, date, datetime, timestamp

I am getting same date time seconds value in JavaScript which is given by `strtotime()` in PHP. But i need same value in JavaScript.

**PHP Code**

```
echo strtotime("2011-01-26 13:51:50");
// 1296046310
```

**JavaScript Code**

```
var d = Date.parse("2011-01-26 13:51:50");
console.log(d);
// 1296030110000
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to use the same time-zone for a sane comparison:

```
echo strtotime("2011-01-26 13:51:50 GMT");
// 1296049910

var d = Date.parse("2011-01-26 13:51:50 GMT") / 1000;
console.log(d);
// 1296049910
```

**Update**

According to the standard, only RFC 2822 formatted dates are well supported:

```
Date.parse("Wed, 26 Jan 2011 13:51:50 +0000") / 1000
```

To generate such a date, you can use `gmdate('r')` in PHP:

```
echo gmdate('r', 1296049910);
```

Comment: Coming `NaN` in Mozilla browser.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript uses milliseconds as a timestamp, whereas PHP uses seconds. As a result, you get very different dates, as it is off by a factor 1000.

**sample**

`echo date('Y-m-d', TIMESTAMP / 1000);`

**Comment Response**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toTimestamp(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)
    {
        var datum = new Date(Date.UTC(year,month-1,day,hour,minute,second));
        return datum.getTime()/1000;
    }

    $(function()
    {
        console.log(toTimestamp(2011,01,26,13,51,50));

    });

</script>

<?php

echo $the_date = strtotime("2011-01-26 13:51:50");
```

Comment: That's not the only difference :)

Comment: @jack i know TIMEZONE also does matter but i just give second difference because first was already given by you

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime()` and `Date.parse()` yield UNIX timestamps with a resolution of seconds and milliseconds respectively. However, if timezone information is missing from the input string, local time is assumed. So the input string `2011-01-26T13:51:50` may produce different output on different machines even if PHP (or JavaScript) is used to generate the timestamps on both machines.

The solution is to explicitly specify the timezone in the strings. This should produce the same result on any machine:

```
Date.parse("Jan 26, 2011 13:51:50 GMT+0500") / 1000; // 1296031910
strtotime("Jan 26, 2011 13:51:50 GMT+0500");         // 1296031910
```